# Return Base64 encoded string from BLOB in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, base64, blob

So I have my LanguageController class in which I have this method:

```
@GetMapping("/languages")
public ResponseEntity<List<Language>> getAllLanguages(@RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
    try {
        List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();

        if (name == null) {
            languageRepository.findAll().forEach(languages::add);
        } else {
            languageRepository.findByNameContaining(name).forEach(languages::add);
        }

        if (languages.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(languages, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

And the Language class is (omitted the getters and setters so it's cleaner):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "languages")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "audio")
    @Lob
    private Blob audio;

    @Column(name = "script")
    @Lob
    private Blob script;

    public Language() {

    }

    public Language(String name, Blob audio, Blob script) {
        this.name = name;
        this.audio = audio;
        this.script = script;
    }
}
```

And here when I consume the API endpoint, I get this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Language",
    "audio": {
      "binaryStream": {},
      "wrappedBlob": {
        "binaryStream": {},
        "traceId": 26,
        "traceObjectName": "blob26"
      }
    },
    "script": {
      "binaryStream": {},
      "wrappedBlob": {
        "binaryStream": {},
        "traceId": 27,
        "traceObjectName": "blob27"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And here I'm returning the BLOB stream, which isn't super useful.

I would like to return the BLOB encoded in Base64, and I just genuinely don't know where to encode the files.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use a `@JsonSerialize` annotation on the `Blob` fields of your entity class to influence how the blobs are serialized. The `SqlBlobSerializer` class seems to be doing the conversion to base64 you are looking for.

```
@Column(name = "audio")
@Lob
@JsonSerialize(using = SqlBlobSerializer.class) 
private Blob audio;
```

- https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html
- https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/SqlBlobSerializer.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the @Entity Language you could return a LanguageDTO instance, the DTO being a class you initialize from the Language instance and in which you convert the Blob in Base64.